# Is it possible to put an increment on unlock_time for every failed login attempt?

Tags: pam, authentication

I have Debian 10.7 machine with a PAM setup:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    required                        pam_deny.so
auth    required    pam_tally2.so    onerr=fail deny=3 unlock_time=180
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
```

This will lock the user for 3 mins if the user failed 3 times.

What I'm trying to achieve is for PAM to increment the `unlock_time` parameter for every unsuccessful attempt. For example, for the first lock fail, the user is locked out for 3 mins. After 3 mins, the user fails again 3 times but now the user is locked out for 6 mins. The variable to increment the unlock_time can be set to anything, can be added and/or multiplied on.

Sample scenario:

```
Failed Attempts: Failed Tries: Unlock Time(secs):
0                3             180
1                3             360
2                3             540
and so on...
```

Is this even possible to do by using the existing options given in pam_tally2 docs?